# How to do rolling distinct count in Redshift?

Tags: count, amazon-redshift, distinct, common-table-expression, rolling-computation

I need to take a rolling LTM unique count of user.
I made a query to generate start and end months:

```
select
    DATEADD('month', ROW_NUMBER() over() - 1, DATE('2019-06-01')) AS start_day,
    DATEADD('month', ROW_NUMBER() over() - 13, DATE('2019-06-01')) AS end_day
from some_table
limit date_diff('month', '2019-05-01', getdate())
```

and i was trying to do something like this but it's throwing an error:

```
with dates as
(
select *
from
    (
    select
        DATEADD('month', ROW_NUMBER() over() - 1, DATE('2019-06-01')) AS start_day,
        DATEADD('month', ROW_NUMBER() over() - 13, DATE('2019-06-01')) AS end_day
    from some_table
    limit date_diff('month', '2019-05-01', getdate())
    ) a
order by 1 desc
)

SELECT
    start_day,
    (
      SELECT
          COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS user_count
      FROM users
      WHERE date BETWEEN end_day AND start_day
    ) a
FROM dates
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 desc;
```

I'm getting an error `ERROR: subquery uses ungrouped column "dates.end_day" from outer query`